# How to dynamically load two or more same or different components at the same view using dynamic content loader in angular4

Tags: angular

I am loading components at model.component.ts dynamically using the [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). This works good for single component loading but getting no view for loading two same or different component. 
How to load two same or different components using the [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)?
Note: I have marked specifically where the problem is in the code?

### service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from 
'@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
@Injectable()
export class DataOrMethodCallService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  jsondta(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Retriving Data from File.......');
    return this.http.get('assets/json/abcd/abc.json')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    alert('Server Error!');
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Then, I am dynamically loading component using a dynamic component loader.

#### modal.component.ts

```
  componentData = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonDataService.jsondta().subscribe(
      data => this.jsdata = data
    );
  }
  //after a click event in some other component below method is called
  showDialog(){
for(let i=0; i<2;i++){   //calling component two times to create components twice.
      this.displayshiftChartComponent(this.jsdata);
}
    }

  displayshiftChartComponent(jsdata) {
    this.componentData[index] = {
      component: CustomShiftChartComponent,
      inputs: {
       shiftData: [
          {
            shiftdata: this.jsdata     
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
```

#### modal.component.html

```
<!-- here loading components dynamically.
     Need to load two or more same components
       or different components here. -->
<!-- need to do something here -->

<div class="col-xs-6">
     <!-- first component load here -->
     <app-dynamic-content-loader [componentData]="componentData[0]">
     </app-dynamic-content-loader>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
     <!-- second component should load here -->
     <app-dynamic-content-loader [componentData]="componentData[1]">
     </app-dynamic-content-loader>
</div>
```

#### shift.component.ts

```
export class CustomShiftChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked {
 constructor(el: ElementRef, public injector: Injector) {
    this.el = el;
    try {
      this.shiftdata = this.injector.get('shiftData')[0].shiftdata;
      this.gridStatus = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error Occured :: ' + e.status);
    }
    if (this.gridStatus === true) {
      alert(this.gridStatus);
      this.shiftdata = this.shiftdata;
      console.log(this.shiftdata);
    }

  ngAfterContentInit() {

  }

}
```

### Dynamic.content-loader.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    ReflectiveInjector, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, Input } from 
    '@angular/core';
    import { CustomShiftChartComponent } from '../components/------';
    import { hellotComponent } from '../hello/-------';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dynamic-content-loader',
      templateUrl: './dynamic-content-loader.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dynamic-content-loader.component.css'],
      entryComponents: [CustomShiftChartComponent,hellotComponent]
    })
    export class DynamicContentLoaderComponent implements OnInit {
      currentComponent = null;
      @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }



      // component: Class for the component you want to create
      // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
      @Input() set componentData(data: { component: any, inputs: any }) {
        // console.log("Component Data :: "+JSON.stringify(data));
        if (!data) {
          return;
        }
        // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
        let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => ({ provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] }));
        const resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

        // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);

        // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

        // We create the component using the factory and the injector
        const component = factory.create(injector);

        // We insert the component into the dom container
        this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);

        // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
        if (this.currentComponent) {
          this.currentComponent.destroy();
        }

        this.currentComponent = component;
      }

      constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

      }

    }
```

Comment: <app-dynamic-content-loader [componentData]="componentData[]"></app-dynamic-content-loader>. If possible, how to load two components (same or different) using this selector. The two components should not overlap.

Comment: You can try using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and route the necessary components based on the conditions

Answer (score 0):

To add a component:

```
addComponent(){
  // check and resolve the component
  var comp = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(YourComponent);
  // Create component inside container
  var forFurtheruse = this.container.createComponent(comp);      
}
```

[See the rest of detail](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1214/angular-2-dynamically-add-remove-components) with working plunker example

Comment: Thanks @Ali, but still in doubt error in my approach above.