# Angular 2 Component Inheritance

Tags: angular

I would like to create an abstract base component which contains the html template.  Methods in the concrete classes extending the base component would supply the data and some other details needed by the base class to create the component.

I would like for the base component to be able to get the name of another component from the concrete component that is to be added to the html template.

For example the base component  might include a template html that looks something like this:

```
<div>Base Component</div>
component: <{{getSelectorName()}}></{{getSelectorName()}}>
```

getSelectorName() could be "ABC-comp" for one concrete implementation and "DEF-comp" for another. Please note that I am just using the  {{}} notation for illustration purposes.

Is this possible?  How would one go about doing that?

Thank you!!!

Comment: `{{}}` is for attribute and property binding and invalid everywhere else. Dynamic component selectors are not supported.

Comment: You can use the same templateUrl and styleUrls for all component you want.

Comment: Use dynamic- content loader for dynamically adding components.   Refer:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055809/how-to-dynamically-load-two-or-more-same-or-different-components-at-the-same-vie

Comment: I do realize the purpose of the {{}} brackets.  I was just using the syntax to be illustrative.  I should have been more clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same templateUrl and styleUrls for all component you want, Therefore you can create a Component "base" and extends all component from this base. Only in constructor use super() and overwrite the function you want change. Becareful width the injected services

```
//Base Component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './app-base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-base.component.css']
})
export class BaseComponent{
    constructor(private servicio:Servicio){}
    funcion1(){}
    function2(){}
} 

//Other component
@Component({
  selector: 'component1-base',
  templateUrl: './app-base.component.html', //<--same html
  styleUrls: ['./app-base.component.css']   //<--same css
})
export class Component1Component extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(servicio:Servicio){
         super(servicio);
         //if you want use servicio you can do
         //this.custom.servicio=servicio
    }
    funcion1(){  
       //this override function1()
       //we can use this.function2()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is precisely my plan.  However in that app-base.component.html, I want the html to include a reference to another component that is dependent upon which implementation has extended this BaseComponent. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader help you (good luck)

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit and override whatever you want, except for templates and styles.

Reference:

https://embed.plnkr.co/hMgaYPVRiXMCiKBdfqHy/